How does Kafka Connect Commit Operation Work?
I am running a CDC pipeline with a PostgreSQL source (Debezium Source Connector) and a PostgreSQL target using the Confluent JDBC Sink Connector (version 10.6.4) to read data from Kafka.

Problem:
How does the interval/frequency  of commit operation is decided?
The below properties I have changed,but frequency of committing remain unchanged.

consumer.override.auto.commit.interval.ms
consumer.override.offset.flush.interval.ms

Apart from this,I have also read the soruce code of Kafka Connect to change the config internally (if possible).
Here is the code snippet for the same
protected void iteration() {
    final long offsetCommitIntervalMs = workerConfig.getLong(WorkerConfig.OFFSET_COMMIT_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG);
    try {
        long now = time.milliseconds();
        if (!committing && (context.isCommitRequested() || now >= nextCommit)) {
            long starttime=System.currentTimeMillis();
            commitOffsets(now, false);
            long endtime=System.currentTimeMillis();
            long diff=endtime-starttime;
            log.trace("Commitstarttime - {} , CommitEndtime - {}, CommitDiff - {}",starttime,endtime,diff);
            nextCommit = now + offsetCommitIntervalMs;
            context.clearCommitRequest();
        }

But I am not able to get the value of OFFSET_COMMIT_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG( it should be 10)
By default, commiting operation is performed after every 10 Seconds
Here are the logs of a particular connector:

Please help me in how can I change this commit interval and by default why the value of 10 seconds is chosen.

Before answering your question I'd like to make sure that we are talking about the same. When we are talking about committing are you talking about "comitting the offsets back to Kafka" or "commit the stuff into the database"?
